# where to init a UITablewView as a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

Where should I initialize a `UITablewView` as a subview, in `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`, in `viewdidload`  or `loadView`? Which is the better approach? Where should I make the frame (I mean which is more effective)?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = kViewBackgroundColor;
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        _tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _tableView.bounces = NO;
        [self addSubview:_tableView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Usualy i do subview init and addsubview in viewdidload

Answer (score 1):

On my projects I usually create a baseViewController with a custom initialiser like this:

```
- (id)init{

    self = [self initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    if (self) {

        //You should create the tableView and other properties here 
        //and add as subviews inside viewDidLoad

        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];

    }
    return self;
}
```

and I always create my view controller by using this `init` method, because I don't think the other vc's need to know the name of the nib file. If I were you I would create subviews inside `init` method, add as subviews inside `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` and finally releasing them inside `dealloc` if you are not using `ARC`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this depends on your requirement that if you are having custom view called with a tableview as subview then loadview with the initwithframe method will be better and while you want to initialize it from viewcontroller then viewdidload is better. I think you should bifurcate your requirement. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are initializing table view with zero frame it wont be visible even if you added that

you can try this

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = kViewBackgroundColor;
        UITableView *_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        _tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _tableView.bounces = NO;
        [_tableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth]
        [self addSubview:_tableView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to create subviews programmatically based on superview metrics (frame or bounds), you should do it in viewDidLoad, because if you do in in initializer, metrics of self.view will not be avaliable, and you subviews will be created with zero frame and will not be visible (as Johnykutty) mentioned above.

But that does not seem to be a good practice in case your subview initialization routines require heavy operations.

Offtopic: I've been codin' for a looong time trying to do everything programmatically, never using xibs, etc. Well, if you ask me now, xibs *really* save your time and make life easier. Consider using interface builder for layout\autolayout, colors\borders etc stuff.